# Plotting percentages in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame with 1800 rows and 2 columns, riskGrp ("1", "2", '3") and mortality (0, 1). What I'd like is a bar chart that shows % mortality by riskGrp. I tried the following, but only got the % mortality that each risk group contributes. Here's my code:

```r
library(tidyverse)

v1 <- data.frame(
  riskGrp = c("Low", "Low", "Low", "Mid", "Mid", "High", "High", "High", "High"), 
  mortality = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1) 
)

ggplot(v1, aes(riskGrp)) + 
  geom_bar(aes( y=mortality/sum(mortality)), stat = "identity") +
  labs(fill = "ICU Disposition", x="Risk Group") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

The graph should have three bars: "Low" with a mortality = 33%, "Mid" with a mortality of 50%, and "High" with a mortality of 75%.
How can I get stratified mortality rates?

Thanks!

Andrew

---

O.K., here's a minimum reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)

v1 <- data.frame(
  riskGrp = c("Low", "Low", "Low", "Mid", "Mid", "High", "High", "High", "High"), 
  mortality = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1) 
)

ggplot(v1, aes(riskGrp)) + 
  geom_bar(aes( y=mortality/sum(mortality)), stat = "identity") +
  labs(fill = "ICU Disposition", x="Risk Group") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

The graph should have three bars: "Low" with a mortality = 33%, "Mid" with a mortality of 50%, and "High" with a mortality of 75%.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I would just aggregate the data beforehand and then plot using `geom_col`:

```
library(tidyverse)

v1 %>%
    group_by(riskGrp) %>%
    summarise(mortality = mean(mortality)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(riskGrp, mortality))+geom_col()+
    scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Low", "Mid", "High"))+
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

Comment: If it solved your problem please consider upvoting and/or accepting my answer